# IPython change input cell syntax highlighting logic for entire session

Tags: python, ipython, syntax-highlighting, jupyter-notebook

You can use extensions or `display` helpers in IPython to make whatever syntax highlighting you'd like on output cells.

For some special cell magics, like `%%javascript` you can also see the input cell itself is rendered with that language's natural syntax highlighting.

How can you cause every input cell to be displayed with some chosen, non-Python syntax highlighting (regardless of any magics used on a cell, regardless of whether the cell embodies Python code, some other language).

In my case I am working with a custom-made cell magic for a proprietary language. The `%%javascript` syntax highlighting works well for this language, but if I have my own `%%proprietarylang` magic function, I obviously can't use `%%javascript` to help me with how the cell is displayed.

Is there a setting I can enable when I launch the notebook, or some property of the `ipython` object itself that can be programmatically set inside of my magic function, which will cause the same display logic to happen as if it was `%%javascript`.

I know that general-purpose on-the-fly syntax highlighting is not supported by the notebook currently. I'm asking specifically about how to make use of pre-existing syntax highlighting effects, such as that of `%%javascript`.

I've seen [some](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/minrk/ipython/blob/master/examples/Notebook/JavaScript%20Notebook%20Extensions.ipynb) [documentation](http://pydoc.net/Python/fortran-magic/0.3/fortranmagic/) referring to `IPython.config.cell_magic_highlight` but this does not seem to exist anymore. Is there a standard replacement for it?

Comment: You might be interested in writing a [kernel](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/wiki/IPython-kernels-for-other-languages) for your language. In IPython 3, kernels can specify what syntax highlighting to use.

Comment: I also [had already asked about that.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28517289/create-language-kernels-for-ipython-for-a-language-without-zeromq-bindings)

Comment: Agreed with thomas on full kernels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace `IPython.config.cell_magic_highlight`, you can use something like

```
import IPython
js = "IPython.CodeCell.config_defaults.highlight_modes['magic_fortran'] = {'reg':[/^%%fortran/]};"
IPython.core.display.display_javascript(js, raw=True)
```

so cells which begin with `%%fortran` will be syntax-highlighted like FORTRAN. (However, they will still be evaluated as python if you do only this.)

Comment: The problem for me is that I'm looking to replace highlighting for cells that will begin with a custom cell magic, not any of the built-ins. I have a proprietary language called flow, and I've written, e.g. `%%flow` to evaluate that language in a cell. I want *that* cell to utilize the built-in JavaScript highlighting. Your solution seems like a good approach for people only dealing with pre-existing magic functions ... whereas I am asking about how to get custom syntax highlighting inside a cell that begins with a *custom* magic function.

Comment: Perhaps I don't really understand what you want do. However, I was trying to add syntax coloring to a cell with a non-standard magic provided by a plugin (To be precise, I wanted @tikz cells provided by the tikzmagic extension to be syntax-highlighted in latex.), and this seems to work appropriately. I believe that using ['magic_javascript'] (or something very similar, perhaps text/javascript is needed) with {'reg':[/^%%flow/]} would do the highlighting you want. But perhaps I am mistaken.

Comment: What version of IPython are you using? When I try this, I get "Javascript error adding output! TypeError: IPython.CodeCell.config_defaults is undefined See your browser Javascript console for more details."

Comment: For example, I can't find `'config_defaults'` anywhere in the [source Javascript code](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/90256320/) for `CodeCell`.

Comment: I see that this appears to literally have just been updated, so after installing the newest IPython release, I am able to get your example to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

For recent IPython version, the selected answer no longer works. The 'config_default' property was renamed options_default (Ipython 6.0.0).
The following works:

```
import IPython
js = "IPython.CodeCell.options_default.highlight_modes['magic_fortran'] = {'reg':[/^%%fortran/]};"
IPython.core.display.display_javascript(js, raw=True)
```