# How to add syntax highlight to SQL line magic, cell magic and custom command in jupyter notebook?

Tags: javascript, python, sql, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I was searching for ways to highlight SQL codes in jupyter notebook.
I was able to highlight SQL cell magic only, but not line magic and custom settings.

## Case 1 (works)

Highlight cell magic (cell startswith %%sql)

Ref: [adding syntax highlighting to Jupyter notebook cell magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43641362/adding-syntax-highlighting-to-jupyter-notebook-cell-magic/43686552)

```
require(['notebook/js/codecell'], function(codecell) {
  codecell.CodeCell.options_default.highlight_modes['magic_text/x-mssql'] = {'reg':[/^%%sql/]} ;
  Jupyter.notebook.events.one('kernel_ready.Kernel', function(){
  Jupyter.notebook.get_cells().map(function(cell){
      if (cell.cell_type == 'code'){ cell.auto_highlight(); } }) ;
  });
});
```

## Case 2(does not work)

Line Magic: line starts with %sql
My attempt: Change the regex to `^%sql`   but it did not work.

```
%sql select * from Products limit 5;
```

## Case 3 (does not work)

How to syntax highlight custom cells (cell startswith ##%%)
My attempt: Tried to changing regex to `^##%%sql`

```
##%%sql
q = " select * from customer limit 2;"
execute_query(q,dbname)
```

## Example image

In the image we can see that cell magic %sql commands are not highlighted.
I want them to be highlighted.
[image]

## Related links

- [adding syntax highlighting to Jupyter notebook cell magic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43641362/adding-syntax-highlighting-to-jupyter-notebook-cell-magic)
- [IPython change input cell syntax highlighting logic for entire session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28703626/ipython-change-input-cell-syntax-highlighting-logic-for-entire-session)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will work even for assignments, as in the third cell. Currently multiple languages highlighting unavailable. So it will be either Python or SQL syntax, whatever comes first.

```
require(['notebook/js/codecell'], function (codecell) {
    codecell.CodeCell.options_default.highlight_modes['magic_text/x-mssql'] = { 'reg': [/%?%sql/] };
    Jupyter.notebook.events.one('kernel_ready.Kernel', function () {
        Jupyter.notebook.get_cells().map(function (cell) {
            if (cell.cell_type == 'code') { cell.auto_highlight(); }
        });
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: How to use this setting?

Comment: Seems like you have to create a `another-custom.js` file in `~/.jupyter/custom` folder like stated here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68340216/any-way-to-bring-back-sql-magic-syntax-highlighting-to-jupyterlab-notebook

Comment: Put the snippet in `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js`

Answer (score 0):

You can open your files in colab's build-in text editor in order to enjoy correct highlights. It opens when you open a text file from the "Files" tab on the left and can be save with "ctr+s" shortcut.