# Any way to bring back %%sql magic syntax highlighting to JupyterLab notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab

So I just recently made a switch from an isolated Conda-based Jupyter Notebook to a JupyterLab notebook, but I noticed that there was no longer a straightforward way of adding syntax highlighting to the `%%sql` cell magic, since the code structure is completely different. Previously, the following code would be added to a `custom.js` file in `~/.jupyter/custom/`:

```
require(['notebook/js/codecell'], function (codecell) {
    codecell.CodeCell.options_default.highlight_modes['magic_text/x-mssql'] = { 'reg': [/%?%sql/] };
    Jupyter.notebook.events.one('kernel_ready.Kernel', function () {
        Jupyter.notebook.get_cells().map(function (cell) {
            if (cell.cell_type == 'code') { cell.auto_highlight(); }
        });
    });
});
```

Now that JupyterLab extensions rely on Python, I'm not sure how I could go about implementing a similar front-end extension for the cell magic.

Comment: https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp

Comment: @krassowski Thanks for the tip! Highlighting for the %%bigquery magic doesn't seem to be working, however, anything specific that needs to be done? (besides having the extension and the google-cloud-bigquery enabled)

Answer (score 1):

Posting [this here](https://jupysql.ploomber.io/en/latest/howto/syntax-highlighting.html), in case someone is still having issues with it. We forked `ipython-sql` and have added support for SQL highlighting using `%%sql` on Jupyter Lab. This is being done through an external plugin on top of Jupyter.

Comment: That link is dead now, can you update it?